# Math equation input and display (like MathQuill) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: math, kotlin

For math expression input in webapps there is an amazing library called [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/).

Is there something along these lines for Jetpack Compose?

Eventually I'm going to want both inline and block rendering of expressions.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @Robby1212 still waiting. The closest thing I found was JLaTeXMath but it was written in Java so converting it would be a reasonably large effort.

Comment: Closest thing I found was https://github.com/vkochenkov/EquationDisplayer, it works pretty well but does have some limitations. (May help someone that stumbles on your question in the future).